# Entity Framework - null reference within many-to-many table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, null, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship with Entity Framework. The relationship itself works - I have a table UserGoals for the relationship between Users and Goals.

The problem: When I try to access the UserGoals data from User, the UserGoals.Goal is null. Likewise, when I try to access UserGoals.User from Goal, it is null as well. This picture should provide some more clarity:

[image: Screenshot of the data structure]

Is it at all possible to access the Goal from there? If not, this will complicate things a lot. I'm wondering if this is possible because if it is, then it would create a circular relationship here (User -> UserGoals -> Goal -> UserGoals -> User -> ad infinitum). On the other hand, I guess Entity Framework and Linq to Entities might handle it.

This is the code I'm using. If it is possible to do what I need, please provide necessary corrections.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Goal> CreatedGoals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserGoal> UserGoals { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Goal> AllGoals
    {
        get
        {
            return CreatedGoals.Union(UserGoals.Select(ug => ug.Goal)).AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}

public class UserGoal
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GoalId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GoalId")]
    public Goal Goal { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(minimum: 1, maximum: 5)]
    public Int16 Priority { get; set; }
}

public class Goal
{
    [Key]
    public int GoalId { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserGoal> UserGoals { get; set; }
}

class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Goal> Goals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.CreatedGoals)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.AuthorId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UserGoals)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Goal>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UserGoals)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.GoalId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your query simply does not load the  `Users` and `Goals` that are attached to your UserGoals. Have you disabled lazy loading? If so you need to write something like `.Include(user=>user.UserGoals.Select(ug=>ug.Goal))`

Comment: I have not disabled lazy loading. Should I do that? If so, where exactly should I call .Include?

Comment: See my answer below. That really should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query simply does not load the `Users` and `Goals` that are attached to your UserGoals. Have you disabled lazy loading? If so you need to write something like `.Include(user => user.UserGoals.Select(ug => ug.Goal))`

A full code snippet:

```
public User GetUser(int userId)
{
   User singleUser = null;

   using(var db = new MyContext())
   {
      var users = from user in db.Users.Include(u => u.UserGoals.Select(ug => ug.Goal))
                where user.UserId == userId
                select user;

      singleUser = users.FirstOrDefault();
   }

   return singleUser;
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. I'll take the liberty to fix a few typos and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you are quering users, can you try calling include("UserGoals") before accessing UserGoals property.

Haven't tried your code myself. If it doesn't work, i'll try it here.

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific? I don't really know how should I call 'include("UserGoals")'.